# Core Plot - Determine & highlight the nearest point when user touch the plot space

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-plot

How to determine & highlight the nearest (x-y major tick) intersection point in coreplotspace when user touch the plot space ('snap to the grid') i.e. highlight the nearest point in the plot space with regular coordinates, even if there is no actual plot point.

Thanks in advance
Kiran Juikar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a "Selection Demo" in the Mac version of *CPTTestApp*. It shows how to draw a plot symbol and crossed lines at a selected plot point using a plot delegate. You can use a plot space delegate instead to get touch events anywhere in the plot area. Use the plot space to convert the event to data coordinates. Each axis has a `majorTickLocations` property that tells you where the tick marks are. Search that set and find the closest one to the selected point.

Comment: Thanks Eric, I could find the nearest point to touch, also checked the selection point demo, but i am facing issue with the next steps. I am looking for the functionality like a geometry pad app (Simple version). It will have  x - y axis, the major ticks locations (grid). Initially graph will be empty & user can add chart/graph points by touching the intersection point (tick locations).

Initially i want to support only line chart, can i support this functionality using core plot. I checked CPTScatterPlot, facing issue with dynamically adding points. Getting me started on this will be helpful.

Comment: Call `-insertDataAtIndex:numberOfRecords:` on the plot each time you need to add data points. It will query the datasource for the new data values.